# What is the difference between straight line and line?

Tags: word-usage, compound-words

Since I belongs to mathematics. I always uses the word straight line in my field. According to us straight line is a locus of all points in which the moving point does not changes its direction or rate of changing direction is constant. Whereas in curve it changes its direction. So we can strictly divide geometrical figures in 2D as straight lines and curves.
My question is what is the use of including straight in straight line. Because we already have words lines and curves to differentiate.

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary?  For example:  *Definition 1.5 (On a map or graph) a curve connecting all points having a specified common property.*  http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/line

Comment: Because *line* can mean other things than it does in mathematics.

Comment: Generally a line i think is any set in an affine space which is parametrizable by a single real variable. Curves would in generally tend to be at least locally differentiable possible globally differentiable.

Comment: You say 'according to us'.  Who is this mysterious 'us' that dictates the meaning of an English word in such a limited way?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I think this might really be a misplaced question. The way I read it it's about mathematical usage of english rather then English. And to answer your question the "us" is mathematicians I'm guessing.:P "We" tend to do things like that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it assumes a restrictive definition of 'line' that is not in general use in the English language.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Common property is it has same slope along the curve. I simply asked which one is proper? Straight line or line? Is there any difference?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Can this be moved to mathematics instead of closed possibly? I think that a reasonable explanation may be had there.

Comment: So you're saying a line can have a constant radius other than the infinite, under its mathematical definition?  And a curve would always have a variable radius?  Sounds like there's a very good reason to use the term 'straight line'.

Comment: @JHCL A point can be locate in a plane by two variables $x$ and $y$, $x$ is the distance from left end($X$-axis) and $y$ is the distance from bottom end($Y$-axis). When we move a point in random, the path traveled by the point is called as locus. If a point moves in such a way that at each point the ratio of $y$ to $x$ is constant(usually geometry of line)  then the path will be straight line(simply line). If that value varies then it is curve. Again am confusing that why should I use straight?

Comment: And according to us sexuals, 'straight' refers to a heterosexual... what does a heterosexual line even mean? Joking aside, you'll have to accept a squiggly line exists outside mathematics.

Comment: @SHREE6174 - your definition of 'line' states: *"or rate of changing direction is constant"*; to my way of thinking, that means it can have a constant radius. Otherwise, what does that phrase mean?

Comment: This is not the place to discuss mathematics, and if the question is about English then it's answered by a dictionary.

Comment: Try over at mathematics.SE. They would know better their preference. (My English copy of Euclid (Heath) consistently uses just 'line')

Comment: "Lines" is the superset of both "straight lines" and "curved lines". As in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve): "In mathematics, a curve (also called a curved line in older texts)". Wikipedia also has a definition of [line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_%28geometry%29). Frankly, there are as many definitions of "line" as there are definitions of "linear", but in all of my calculus, differential equations, and signal processing courses, if you could parameterize it in terms of one variable s, it was called a line. source: I'm an engineering student at a top 20 U.S. uni.

Answer (score 4):

**Answer**

1. The mathematical definition of *line* that you offer is specific to the field you are talking about. You appear have defined all lines to be straight.  Clearly you can eliminate the word 'straight' under that definition.
2. In English in general, you need to accept dictionary definitions of 'line'. These include non-straight versions, e.g.

> **line**
>
> 1.5 (On a map or graph) a curve connecting all points having a specified common property.
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/line)

Comment: Concerning part 1 of this answer: I think the OP intended to define "line" in such a way that all lines are straight, but by including the clause "or rate of changing direction is constant" the definition also includes circles among the lines.

Comment: @AndreasBlass - Well that simply means the OP defines a circle to be a straight line. Maybe that is acceptable in the OP's type of maths. It certainly doesn't apply here on the English Language & Usage site.